# How to set the remote API version for docker client?

Tags: docker

When I try to connect to a remote host using the docker client like this:

```
docker -H tcp://remothost:5555 ps
```

I get an error for mismatched version:

```
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.16, server: 1.15)
```

So how do I set the client so it uses version 1.15(instead of 1.16) so it matches the API version of the remote host?

Comment: There's an issue for this in Docker [Proposal: Override ApiVersion in client](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11486)

Answer (score 0):

From docker [reference:](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api/)

> The current version of the API is v1.16
>
> Calling /info is the same as calling /v1.16/info.
>
> You can still call an old version of the API using /v1.15/info.

Comment: So how do I set the docker client to use `/v1.15/` instead?

Comment: You shouldn't have to - is this a boot2docker instance? you may need to update your docker on the remote.

Comment: What about downgrading your client to test?

Comment: How do you downgrade the client API version?

Comment: Install an older version of docker.